# SLK - Assignement List Web Part is missing

Tags: sharepoint, slk

I deployed and activated the SharePoint Learning Kit (SLK) to my SharePoint 2013 Foundation according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG07se2R_pg) video. In the video there is a Web Part called "Assignment List Web Part". But I don't have this one in my Web Part Collection.

I have all SLK Features activated but the Web Part is still missing.

Is my solution corrupted or is SLK not capable with SharePoint 2013 Foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to activate the WebPart on Site Collection level.

1. Select Site Actions | Site Settings to get to the site setting page.
2. Under Site Collection Administration select Site Collection Features.
3. Activate the feature.

This will add the "Assignment List Web Part" to the WebPart gallery.

http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2010/07/sharepoint-learning-kit-1-5-features-you-can-activate/

For further questions regarding SLK, you might ask them on the [Codeplex SLK Discussion Board](https://slk.codeplex.com/discussions).
There you have the chance to discuss your questions with other people facing the same problems and even the developer himself.

Comment: You are my savior today GrindelOh! Big thanks for your detailed answers and guidelines!